# Braintree Discount - PHP NotFound in Util.php line 64:

Tags: php, braintree

I am trying to override the discount amount i have created from Braintree control panel by calling the function below.

```
$result = Braintree_Subscription::create([
    'paymentMethodToken' => 'the_payment_method_token',
    'planId' => 'the_plan_id',
    'addOns' => [
        'add' => [
            [
                'inheritedFromId' => 'abcd',
                'amount' => 20.00
            ]
        ]
    ]
]);
```

But it is returning me this error 
**NotFound in Util.php line 64:; Util::throwStatusCodeException('404') in Http.php line 47** Appreciate any help. Thanks!

Comment: What are the details of the planID as well as the addon ID you are passing in? My guess is there's a conflict or a duplicate of some sort.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://www.braintreepayments.com/contact).</sub>

The 404 error you're seeing is likely being thrown due to one or more ID's specified in your API call not matching what you have in your control panel. The two ID's from your example code are the following:

A Plan with the ID **the_plan_id**

An add-on with the ID **abcd**

You'll want to ensure that you have a plan and add-on with those ID's in your control panel before using them in an API call. Since there isn't a way to generate plans or ID's from the API, you can follow the guide below on how to make them.

[Making a Plan](https://articles.braintreepayments.com/guides/recurring-billing/plans)

The other potential issue here is that in your question, you mentioned you wanted to use a *discount*, where in your code, you're specifying an *add-on*. This might itself be the source of the problem. I would change these lines:

```
'addOns' => [
        'add' => [
            [
                'inheritedFromId' => 'abcd',
                'amount' => 20.00
            ]
        ]
```

to

```
'discounts' => [
        'add' => [
            [
                'inheritedFromId' => 'abcd',
                'amount' => 20.00
            ]
        ]
```